# vim/gvim formatting (%!column -t) not working, instead it filters all lines

Tags: vim, formatting, reformatting

When using `%!column -t`, or when giving list of lines to operate such as `%10,15!column -t`, vim opens a pop-up for column instead. On exiting pop-up it just filters all lines to which code was applied.

This used to work fine before, not sure if I accidentally changed something in my `.gvimrc`/

[image: "column pop-up image"]

Comment: Hard to say anything about your `gvimrc` without seeing it. Also, is that window a Vim window?

Comment: Looks like you are running a gui-program called `column`, and not the expected bash program `column`.

Comment: Go into your regular terminal, and type `which column` or run `column`. Do you get the usual column utility, or this GUI one?

Comment: On regular terminal "which column" returns /usr/bin/column, but calling directly column command just freezes the terminal. 

In my gvimrc, apart from syntax on, key mappings and general commands such as set nu, ai, etc. I additionally have "set nocompatible" because my mappings were not working before. 

Also, the gui in image above is not the gvim window but the pop-up that opens on using :!column -t